# Disable file download link for BINARY columns in phpMyAdmin >4.3.0

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL database, where I use a `binary(36)` column for the unique `id` in all of my tables.

When **phpMyAdmin 4.3.0** was introduced, it looks like they added a feature where BLOB and BINARY type columns would display their data as a link, and clicking the link would let you download the file (in my case, a **.bin** file is downloaded).

[image: Clicking the ID downloads a .bin file]

If you want to edit the data, you have to click on an empty part of the cell to open the "edit" mode.

I can see this being useful, but in my case, I am not interested in the .bin file it downloads.

In older versions of phpMyAdmin (e.g. **4.1.0**), this feature is not available (or at least, is not enabled by default). You could simply click the text shown, and the edit dialog would pop up.

[image: Clicking the ID opens up the edit dialog]

I've looked through [phpMyAdmin's Documentation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html) and haven't been able to find a setting that disables this. There is the [`$cfg['ProtectBinary']`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_ProtectBinary) setting, but I already have that set to `blob`, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Ideally I'd like to use the latest version of phpMyAdmin, but only if I can change this setting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/phpmyadmin/latest/phpmyadmin.pdf says:

```
$cfg[’ProtectBinary’]
Type boolean or string
Default value ’blob’
Defines whether BLOB or BINARY columns are protected from editing when browsing a table’s content. Valid
values are:
•false to allow editing of all columns;
•’blob’ to allow editing of all columns except BLOBS;
•’noblob’ to disallow editing of all columns except BLOBS (the opposite of ’blob’);
•’all’ to disallow editing of all BINARY or BLOB columns.
```

So as the default value is 'blob', you should set it to false:

```
$cfg[’ProtectBinary’] = false;
```

Comment: That setting doesn't remove the `<a>` link. It only changes how my EXPORT looks.

Comment: Setting `$cfg[’ProtectBinary’] = false;` or `$cfg['DisplayBinaryAsHex'] = true;`, or any other combination, does not remove the hyperlinks on those BINARY cols. Those settings don't affect the hyperlinks, which is the problem I'm running into.

Comment: Ok, the solution seems to be a little bit more complicated - the key word is **transformations**: 
http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/transformations.html

Comment: Transformations looks like it is leading in the right direction, but haven't had enough time to thoroughly find what I need in there. I'll try to update this when I find it.